# How do you use MyList.Contains(MyObject) when NHibernate populates MyList with Proxy Elements

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I have an NHibernate many-to-many relationship.  Before adding an item to the relationship I want to test whether the item already exists in the collection.  My Add method looks like

```
public virtual void AddCourse(Course course)
{
    if (!this.Courses.Contains(course))
    {
        course.Students.Add(this);
        this.Courses.Add(course);
    }
}
```

The Courses.Contains(course) statement always fails.  I've done some digging and realised that the Courses list is a list of NHibernate proxies not my domain objects.  For my sanity I knocked up a test that has shown that I have equality set up to work correctly.  The test also showed that Contains doesn't work on a subclass.

I've disabled lazy-loading on the Courses collection and the code works fine.

So, how do you do this with Lazy-loaded objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't test it right now on my machine, but have some ideas:

1. check using GetHashCode:

   ```
   if (!this.Courses.Any(r => r.GetHashCode() == course.GetHashCode()))
   ```
2. check using unique property of the `Course`. For example, Id:

   ```
   if (!this.Courses.Any(r => r.Id == course.Id))
   ```

Both expressions used `System.Linq` namespace (don't forget to include it before).
IMHO, the second example is the better one.

Comment: I've gone with this method for the time but it still feels like a hack.

Comment: If it works, then this is a solution. No matter it is a hack or 'certificated and approved by blablasoft best patterns and practices etc.'

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...

Pardon my VB, but have you tried doing a manual checkthrough of the elements? i.e.

```
For Each itemIn In me.Courses
    If itemIn Is course
        course.Students.Add(this);
        this.Courses.Add(course)
    End If
Next
```

These explicit calls to each item in the list might force the items to be properly loaded.

I think the key here is that you'll need to make an "energetic" enough call to the elements of your List to overcome the laziness, though I'd guess you know this. I think it's more or less what Genius' answer is trying to do, as well, but I'm not absolutely sure.